# Why is Ruby source code maintained by two version control systems?

Tags: ruby, git, svn, github

Why is Ruby maintained by both a SVN repo `http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/trunk`[1](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/trunk) as guided by the official website, and mean while under a git repo `https://github.com/ruby/ruby` [2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) at github with active issues and pull requests?

How does the community manage to merge, say, code contributed to the SVN repo to the Git repo and vice versa?

Comment: read https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3031344 that should explain why

Comment: @bjhaid thanks for the link but it seems to be discussing about ruby-gnome2 instaed of ruby.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking the wrong people, you should be asking the Ruby maintainers.

Comment: git can speak subversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVN repository is where the development happens.

The mirror at github is also an SVN repository since github supports those.

Comment: I once submitted a patch from github and it was merged into the core, so I doubt this is true